# Debezium cannot start streaming after complete snapshot due to Producer failure

Tags: postgresql, debezium

I am using Debezium for Change Data Capture(CDC) on PostgreSQL database.
My source database have about 160 tables with total 700m records. I always get Error when the snapshot stage completed and start streaming, it causes debezium to restart the snapshot again. At the time snapshot completed, the replication slot size is about 40GB.
When I try start the connector to apply for only a few tables not all, it works well without any error. So I am wondering is the problem comes from some of the other tables or is it because the replication slot size is too large and cause high load and can not start streaming.
Bellow is my source connector , and the error stack trace.

```
{
    "name": "main-connector-prod-1",
    "config": {
        "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresConnector",
        "tasks.max": "1",
        "topic.prefix": "sink-db-main-prod",
        "metrics.prefix": "sink-db-main-prod",
        "signal.kafka.topic": "sink-db-main-prod-signal",
        "signal.data.collection": "public.debezium_signal",
        "publication.name": "db_main_prod_publication",
        "slot.name": "db_main_prod",
        "snapshot.mode": "initial",
        "database.server.name": "postgres",
        "database.hostname": "***",
        "database.port": "***",
        "database.user": "***",
        "database.password": "***",
        "database.server.id": "1",
        "database.dbname": "***",
        "table.include.list": "public.***",
        "heartbeat.interval.ms": "5000",
        "schema.history.internal.kafka.bootstrap.servers": "kafka:9092",
        "schema.history.internal.kafka.topic": "schema-changes.inventory",
        "max.request.size": "104857600",
        "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
        "key.converter.schemas.enable": "true",
        "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
        "value.converter.schemas.enable": "true",
        "plugin.name": "pgoutput",
        "publication.autocreate.mode": "all_tables",
        "time.precision.mode": "connect",
        "max.batch.size": "40960",
        "max.queue.size": "163840",
        "offset.flush.timeout.ms": "60000",
        "offset.flush.interval.ms": "10000",
        "skipped.operations": "none",
        "snapshot.fetch.size": "51200",
        "snapshot.max.threads": "3"
    }
}
```

Error:

```
2023-10-16 23:14:06,058 INFO   Postgres|sink-db-main-prod|streaming  No incremental snapshot in progress, no action needed on start   [io.debezium.pipeline.source.snapshot.incremental.AbstractIncrementalSnapshotChangeEventSource]
2023-10-16 23:14:06,058 INFO   Postgres|sink-db-main-prod|streaming  Starting streaming   [io.debezium.pipeline.ChangeEventSourceCoordinator]
2023-10-16 23:14:06,058 INFO   Postgres|sink-db-main-prod|streaming  Retrieved latest position from stored offset 'LSN{70A/FF28BBF0}'   [io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresStreamingChangeEventSource]
2023-10-16 23:14:06,060 INFO   Postgres|sink-db-main-prod|streaming  Looking for WAL restart position for last commit LSN 'null' and last change LSN 'LSN{70A/FF28BBF0}'   [io.debezium.connector.postgresql.connection.WalPositionLocator]
2023-10-16 23:14:06,061 INFO   Postgres|sink-db-main-prod|streaming  Initializing PgOutput logical decoder publication   [io.debezium.connector.postgresql.connection.PostgresReplicationConnection]
2023-10-16 23:14:06,124 ERROR  Postgres|sink-db-main-prod|streaming  Producer failure   [io.debezium.pipeline.ErrorHandler]
io.debezium.jdbc.JdbcConnectionException: An I/O error occurred while sending to the backend.
        at io.debezium.connector.postgresql.connection.PostgresReplicationConnection.initPublication(PostgresReplicationConnection.java:193)
        at io.debezium.connector.postgresql.connection.PostgresReplicationConnection.initConnection(PostgresReplicationConnection.java:408)
        at io.debezium.connector.postgresql.connection.PostgresReplicationConnection.startStreaming(PostgresReplicationConnection.java:317)
        at io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresStreamingChangeEventSource.execute(PostgresStreamingChangeEventSource.java:138)
        at io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresStreamingChangeEventSource.execute(PostgresStreamingChangeEventSource.java:41)
        at io.debezium.pipeline.ChangeEventSourceCoordinator.streamEvents(ChangeEventSourceCoordinator.java:174)
        at io.debezium.pipeline.ChangeEventSourceCoordinator.executeChangeEventSources(ChangeEventSourceCoordinator.java:141)
        at io.debezium.pipeline.ChangeEventSourceCoordinator.lambda$start$0(ChangeEventSourceCoordinator.java:109)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: An I/O error occurred while sending to the backend.
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:383)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:496)
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:413)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:333)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeCachedSql(PgStatement.java:319)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:295)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeQuery(PgStatement.java:244)
        at io.debezium.connector.postgresql.connection.PostgresReplicationConnection.initPublication(PostgresReplicationConnection.java:154)
        ... 12 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
        at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:186)
        at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:140)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.read(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:484)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.readHeader(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:478)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.bytesInCompletePacket(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:70)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readApplicationRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1455)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl$AppInputStream.read(SSLSocketImpl.java:1066)
        at org.postgresql.core.VisibleBufferedInputStream.readMore(VisibleBufferedInputStream.java:161)
        at org.postgresql.core.VisibleBufferedInputStream.ensureBytes(VisibleBufferedInputStream.java:128)
        at org.postgresql.core.VisibleBufferedInputStream.ensureBytes(VisibleBufferedInputStream.java:113)
        at org.postgresql.core.VisibleBufferedInputStream.read(VisibleBufferedInputStream.java:73)
        at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.receiveChar(PGStream.java:453)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2120)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:356)
        ... 19 more
```

Does anyone face the same problem?

Comment: Did you try looking on the DB side for some statement timeout configurations? Maybe the DB is cutting the connection Debezium established due to inactivity or something, as 160 tables is quite something.

Comment: @TudorPlugaru Thanks a lot. I solved the problem by running Debezium and Kafka in the same network with source database instead of connect to the source database from outside. Maybe it's due to network connectivity or bandwith or something.